# tikzexternalize and savebox error

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-external

When trying out [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263224/78282) but with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

instead of `\documentclass[tikz,border=2]{standalone}`, I had the same problem as described in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284638/tikzexternalize-optimizes-away-savebox-boxes).
I tried implementing the answer by adding `\tikzset{external/optimize=false}` in each savebox declaration, but I get an error.

Here's the code (I marked changes to the original with `%here`, had to shorten it because of SX character limit):

```
\documentclass{article} %here
\usepackage{tikz} %here
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} %here
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} %here
\tikzexternalize %here

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,calc}
\tikzstyle{connector} = [->,thick]

\newsavebox\myboxa
\savebox\myboxa{%
\tikzset{external/optimize=false} %here
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
width=4cm,
]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (2,-3) (4,5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=3in,y=2in]
    \tikzstyle{ann} = [draw=none,fill=none,right]
    \matrix[nodes={draw, thick, fill=none},
    row sep=0.3cm,column sep=0.5cm] {
        \node[draw=none,fill=none,label={below:$\mathbf{u}$}] (N1) {\usebox\myboxa}; &
        \node[rectangle, minimum height=0.5in, minimum width = 0.75in] (N2) {Center}; &
        \node[draw=none,label={below:$\mathbf{y}$}] (N3) {\usebox\myboxa};\\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It gives me the error

> ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape
>   -halt-on-e rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "texstudio_n32112-figure0" "\def\tikzexter
>   nalrealjob{texstudio_n32112}\input{texstudio_n32112}"' did NOT result
>   in a usab le output file 'texstudio_n32112-figure0' (expected one of
>   .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png :). Please verify that you have enabled system
>   calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pd flatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it
>   is also named 'write 18' or something like  that. Or maybe the command
>   simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'texst
>   udio_n32112-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the
>   picture.

The given log file says

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.10.9)  25 FEB 2016 16:03
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\def\tikzexternalrealjob{texstudio_n32112}\input{texstudio_n32112}
(./texstudio_n32112.tex (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (c:/texlive/
2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/te
x/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/ut
ilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box26
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
)) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (c:/texlive/20
14/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 94.
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (c:/texlive/
2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen107
\pgf@y=\dimen108
\pgf@xa=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@xb=\dimen111
\pgf@yb=\dimen112
\pgf@xc=\dimen113
\pgf@yc=\dimen114
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count88
\c@pgf@countb=\count89
\c@pgf@countc=\count90
\c@pgf@countd=\count91
\t@pgf@toka=\toks19
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks21
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2014/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.35)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count92
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count93
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (c:/texlive/2
014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex (c:/texlive/2014/texmf
-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/te
x/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen115
\pgfmath@count=\count94
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex))) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat
.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count95
)) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.te
x
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen117
\pgf@picminy=\dimen118
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen121
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen122
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen123
\pgf@xx=\dimen124
\pgf@xy=\dimen125
\pgf@yx=\dimen126
\pgf@yy=\dimen127
\pgf@zx=\dimen128
\pgf@zy=\dimen129
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen130
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen131
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen132
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen133
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count96
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen134
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen135
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen136
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen137
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.te
x
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen138
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen139
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count97
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
)) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.te
x
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
))) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.te
x
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21  (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen140
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen141
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
)) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (c:/texlive/2
014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/
tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/la
tex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfma
th.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code
.tex
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen142
\pgffor@skip=\dimen143
\pgffor@stack=\toks25
\pgffor@toks=\toks26
)) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count98
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen144
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen145
\tikz@lasty=\dimen146
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen147
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen148
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen149
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen150
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box34
\tikz@tempbox=\box35
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box36
\tikztreelevel=\count99
\tikznumberofchildren=\count100
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count101
\tikz@fig@count=\count102
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count103
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count104
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count105
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count106

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
))) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks27
\ex@=\dimen151
)) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen152
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count107
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count108
\leftroot@=\count109
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count110
\DOTSCASE@=\count111
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box37
\strutbox@=\box38
\big@size=\dimen153
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count112
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count113
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count114
\dspbrk@lvl=\count115
\tag@help=\toks28
\row@=\count116
\column@=\count117
\maxfields@=\count118
\andhelp@=\toks29
\eqnshift@=\dimen154
\alignsep@=\dimen155
\tagshift@=\dimen156
\tagwidth@=\dimen157
\totwidth@=\dimen158
\lineht@=\dimen159
\@envbody=\toks30
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks31
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty (c:/texlive/2014/
texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex)
Package: pgfplots 2015/05/02 v1.12.1 Data Visualization (1.12.1)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.code.tex (c:/texlive/
2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscore.code.tex
\t@pgfplots@toka=\toks32
\t@pgfplots@tokb=\toks33
\t@pgfplots@tokc=\toks34
\pgfplots@tmpa=\dimen160
\c@pgfplots@coordindex=\count119
\c@pgfplots@scanlineindex=\count120

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgfplotssysgeneric.code.te
x)) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgfplotslibrary.code.
tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfs
upp_loader.code.tex (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgfli
braryfpu.code.tex)) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfpl
otsutil.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsliststru
cture.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsliststru
ctureext.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsarray.co
de.tex
\c@pgfplotsarray@tmp=\count121
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsmatrix.c
ode.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstableshared.c
ode.tex
\c@pgfplotstable@counta=\count122
\t@pgfplotstable@a=\toks35
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsdeque.co
de.tex) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.co
de.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.data.code.
tex))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.verb.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfsh
ading.code.tex
\c@pgfplotslibrarysurf@no=\count123

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfsha
ding.pgfsys-pdftex.def)))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolormap.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolor.code.tex)) 
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsstackedplots.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.t
ex)) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.scaling.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscoordprocessing.code.t
ex) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.errorbars.code.te
x) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.markers.code.tex) 
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsticks.code.tex) (c:/te
xlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.paths.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarydecorations.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecorations.code.t
ex
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen161
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen162
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen163
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen164
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen165
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count124
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen166
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen167
)
\tikz@lib@dec@box=\box39
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydec
orations.pathmorphing.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydec
orations.pathreplacing.code.tex))
\pgfplots@numplots=\count125
\pgfplots@xmin@reg=\dimen168
\pgfplots@xmax@reg=\dimen169
\pgfplots@ymin@reg=\dimen170
\pgfplots@ymax@reg=\dimen171
\pgfplots@zmin@reg=\dimen172
\pgfplots@zmax@reg=\dimen173
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryplotmarks.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplotmarks.code.
tex
File: pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2015/08/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.14)
)))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarypositioning.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex 2008/10/06 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.exter
nal.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/libraries/tikzlibraryex
ternal.code.tex (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (./tikzexternalshared.code.tex))
Package pgfplots external lib: loading complementary code for your PGF version.
..

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfs
upp_pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box40
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfs
upp_tikzlibraryexternal.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfs
upp_tikzexternalshared.code.tex)))
No auxiliary output files.

\w@pgfexternal@auxout=\write4

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryshapes.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryshapes.geometric.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1
)

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.g
eometric.code.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex 2008/06/26 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)

))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryshapes.misc.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.m
isc.code.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.misc.code.tex 2013/07/18 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.5)
))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryshapes.symbols.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.s
ymbols.code.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex 2013/09/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.6)
))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryshapes.arrows.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.a
rrows.code.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex 2008/06/26 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryshapes.callouts.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.c
allouts.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryshapes.multipart.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1
)

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.m
ultipart.code.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex 2010/01/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)

\pgfnodepartlowerbox=\box41
\pgfnodeparttwobox=\box42
\pgfnodepartthreebox=\box43
\pgfnodepartfourbox=\box44
\pgfnodeparttwentybox=\box45
\pgfnodepartnineteenbox=\box46
\pgfnodeparteighteenbox=\box47
\pgfnodepartseventeenbox=\box48
\pgfnodepartsixteenbox=\box49
\pgfnodepartfifteenbox=\box50
\pgfnodepartfourteenbox=\box51
\pgfnodepartthirteenbox=\box52
\pgfnodeparttwelvebox=\box53
\pgfnodepartelevenbox=\box54
\pgfnodeparttenbox=\box55
\pgfnodepartninebox=\box56
\pgfnodeparteightbox=\box57
\pgfnodepartsevenbox=\box58
\pgfnodepartsixbox=\box59
\pgfnodepartfivebox=\box60
)))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarysnakes.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarysnakes.code.tex 2013/07/15 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)

Package pgf Warning: Snakes have been superseded by decorations. Please use the
 decoration libraries instead of the snakes library on input line 14.


(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarydecorations.shapes.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydec
orations.shapes.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarycalc.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex 2013/07/15 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
\myboxa=\box61
\myboxb=\box62
\openout4 = `texstudio_n32112-figure0.dpth'.

! Undefined control sequence.
\pgf@externalend ... \pgfexternal@originalshipout 
                                                  \box 0 \gdef \pgfexternal@...
l.24 }

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 23043 strings out of 494216
 611295 string characters out of 6160714
 759925 words of memory out of 5000000
 26013 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4094 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 417 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 72i,11n,105p,786b,1912s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Is there any robust way of using plots in nodes *and* `\tikzexternalize`?

Comment: Are you using -shell-escape when you compile?

Comment: yes, I am using the following command: `"C:/texlive/2014/bin/win32/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` and externalization is working for other tikzpictures

Comment: It works for me if you put the definition of `\myboxa` after \begin{document}

Comment: indeed, and the definition was after `\begin{document}`, too, in the [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/284677/78282) I was referring to. I didn't notice that, thanks for pointing that out! Now I lack the understanding how `\tikzset{external/optimize=false` to get an idea why it needs to be in the main body.

Comment: can't help with that! :)

Comment: No problem! Making it work helps me more than understanding why something doesn't work. ;)